# How to create a cooldown decorator

Tags: python, python-3.x, decorator, python-decorators

**I am trying to create a cooldown decorator in Python 3. Ideal usage is as follows:**

```py
@cooldown(duration=2)
def func(string):
  print(string)
```

Then...

```py
func('1st attempt') # should work (as cooldown == 0) and reset cooldown (cooldown = 2)
func('2nd attempt') # should fail (as cooldown != 0)
func.update_cooldown() # should decrease cooldown (cooldown -= 1)
func('3rd attempt') # should also fail (as cooldown != 0)
func.update_cooldown() # should decrease cooldown (cooldown -= 1)
func('4th attempt') # should work (as cooldown == 0) and reset cooldown (cooldown = 2)
```

**My code (Python 3.8):**

```py
import functools

def cooldown(duration):
    def decorator(method):
        cooldown = 0

        @functools.wraps(method)
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            nonlocal cooldown
            if cooldown <= 0:
                cooldown = duration
                return method(*args, **kwargs)
            print(f'Cooldown active, {cooldown} updates remaining')

        return wrapper
    return decorator
```

**How would I add the ability to decrease the cooldown counter for a specific decorated function? and how would I adapt it to work with class methods?**

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def cooldown(duration):
    def decorator(method):
        cooldown = 0

        @functools.wraps(method)
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            nonlocal cooldown
            if cooldown <= 0:
                cooldown = duration
                return method(*args, **kwargs)
            print(f"Cooldown active, {cooldown} updates remaining")

        def update_cooldown():
            nonlocal cooldown
            cooldown -= 1

        wrapper.update_cooldown = update_cooldown
        return wrapper

    return decorator
```

`cooldown` variable is unique per decorated function, because in each cooldown call you define new decorator function `def decorator(method):`, and new cooldown counter inside.

It already works for classmethods:

```
class A:
    @classmethod
    @cooldown(duration=2)
    def a(cls):
        print("whatever")

A.a() # whatever
A.a() # Cooldown active, 2 updates remaining
A.a.update_cooldown() 
A.a() # Cooldown active, 1 updates remaining
```